# Relation between orbitals and cosets of point stabilizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $\Omega$. Then there exists a natural action of $G$ on $\Omega \times \Omega$ given by $(\alpha, \beta)^x = (\alpha^x, \beta^x)$. The orbits on $\Omega\times \Omega$ are called orbitals. For an orbital $\Delta$ and $\alpha \in \Omega$ set
$$ 
 \Delta(\alpha) := \{ \beta \in \Omega : (\alpha, \beta) \in \Delta \}.
$$

If $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$, and $\Delta(\alpha^x) = \Delta(\alpha^y)$, does this implies that $G_{\alpha} x = G_{\alpha} y$?
(Of course by $G_{\alpha} x = G_{\alpha} y \Leftrightarrow \alpha^x = \alpha^y$ the reverse implication holds).

Comment: I think the dihedral group of order $8$ acting on $4$ points is a counterexample. $G = \langle (1,2,3,4),(2,4) \rangle$, $\alpha=1$, $\beta=3$, $x=(1,3)(2,4)$,

Comment: Orbitals correspond to double cosets $G_\alpha xG_\alpha$ of the point stabilizer, not cosets.